# Why the indefinite article in "my son has a swollen left eye"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

"My son has a swollen eye." is correct English, meaning only one eye is swollen, out of two. But why do we say "My son has a swollen left eye" rather than "the swollen left eye", even though he only has one left eye?

Comment: Thank you everyone. Now I clearly understand the use of “a” in my mind. I am taking back what I said earlier about the “domain expansion” between the two sentences – “My son has a swollen eye” and “My son has a swollen left eye”. My conclusion is that both sentences have the same domain containing millions of eyes. The article “a” must always imply multiple THINGS in the domain, not just one THING. So, even in the first sentence “My son has a swollen eye” there must be many THINGS – and, here, the THINGS are not “eyes” but rather “swollen eyes”. My son presumably has only one swollen eye, so h

Comment: I am finishing my comment above: My son presumably has only one swollen eye, so he cannot be a domain candidate. The sentence is talking about one “swollen eye” out of millions of swollen eyes out there… just like the second sentence “My son has a swollen left eye” refers to one “swollen left eye” out of millions in the world.

Answer (score 1):

It's an instance of the same quasi-indefiniteness that occurs in an expression like "He has a heart as big as all outdoors." The idea in the latter case isn't that the person has multiple hearts, one of which is large, but that his heart in comparison to others or to a typical heart is a large one.

Something similar is at work in the example of the son's swollen left eye. Though it is his only left eye, it is still a left eye among the millions of such eyes that exist or that we can imagine—and his is a swollen one. It is not correct idiomatic English to say, "My son has the swollen left eye" unless we have prefaced that sentence with another statement such as "One person in the room has chronic lumbago, and another person there has a swollen left eye"—and of course, even then, we have set up the use of the definite article by preceding it with an introduction that uses an indefinite article.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Based on your explanation, I made the following observation about the English article. "My son has a swollen eye" means one eye out of two. "My son has a swollen left eye" suddenly expands the domain from his body having two eyes to the rest of the world containing a billion left eyes.

Comment: And, of course, "My son has the flu" suggests he has the same flu others have.

Answer (score 0):

When discussing general conditions of body parts, sometimes English uses the indefinite article, and sometimes no article at all:

> Fred had a headache.
>   Ned had a sprained ankle.
>   Ed had a cold.
>
> Fran has arthritis.
>   Ann has thyroid cancer.
>   Dan has depression.

But on the other hand, if you really were talking without adjacent adjectives about his left eye.  You would use a definite article. *His* or *your* or *the* left eye.

> You have something in *your* left eye.
>   (talking to someone else) Be sure to check *the* left eye.  It is swollen.
>   (or possibly) Be sure to check *his* left eye.  It is swollen.

Comment: It seems like you are saying it is OK to say "My son has the swollen left eye". My question does not have to be related to maladies. "My dog has a green eye" meaning the other eye is brown. "My dog has a green left eye" or "the green left eye"?

Comment: You're right.  I suppose it's more discussing a __condition__ rather than a malady.  It seems if you switch to "has a stick in" or "has a huge pupil in", you no longer use the indefinite article.  Both of those would use a definite article.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Also, it seems to do with the adjacent adjective.